# How can React useEffect watch and update state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

## Example code

```js
export function useShape (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    shape: 'square',
    size: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }
  })

  // Change shape name while size update
  useEffect(()=>{
    const {size: {width, height}} = state

    setState({
      ...state,
      shape: width===height ? 'square' : 'rect'
    })
  }, [state, state.size])
}
```

## Expected

When size updated, the side effect will change the size name based on width,height.

The goal is to make state consistent, so I will always get the correct shape no matter how size changes.

## But got problem

The useEffect function got into a loop, if I remove the 'state' dependence it will be good, but the intelliSense requested 'state' dependence, so what's the solution?

Comment: Each state value should be stored with its own useState hook, don't store all your state in the same object. Not to mention that you shouldn't be storing computed values as state at all. If the value of shape can be calculated from size, then don't store the shape in state, just compute it when you need it.

Comment: I tried it doesn't complain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out this [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-cdn-uv39n?file=/src/App.js) for the solution

The infinite loop is due to placing "state" as a dependency while modifying the state itself in useEffect.

The solution is to decouple your state, by keeping your view variable separate from your controlled variables.

this is how you can define your useShape hook.

```
function useShape() {
  const [shape, setShape] = useState("square");
  const [dimension, setDimension] = useState({
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });

  // Change shape name while size update
  useEffect(() => {
    const { height, width } = dimension;

    setShape(height === width ? "square" : "react");
  }, [dimension, dimension.height, dimension.width]);

  return [shape, setDimension];
}
```

this way you can expose your Dimension setter, and you view variable as independent Pieces.

Answer (score 8):

> The useEffect function got into a loop...

That's because you create a new object for `state` every time, and `state` is listed as a dependency.

When using hooks, instead of building multi-part state objects, you're usually better off using smaller pieces. In this case, I'd use three:

```
const [shape, setShape] = useState("square");
const [width, setWidth] = useState(100);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);

useEffect(() => {
    setShape(width === height ? "square" : "rect");
}, [width, height]);
```

Now, what you're setting (`shape`) isn't a dependency of the effect hook, so it won't fire endlessly.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {
    const [shape, setShape] = useState("square");
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(100);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setShape(width === height ? "square" : "rect");
    }, [width, height]);

    function onWidthInput({target: {value}}) {
        setWidth(+value);
    }

    function onHeightInput({target: {value}}) {
        setHeight(+value);
    }

    return <div>
        <div>
            Width: <input type="number" value={width} onInput={onWidthInput} />
        </div>
        <div>
            Height: <input type="number" value={height} onInput={onHeightInput} />
        </div>
        <div>
            Shape: {shape}
        </div>
    </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You can probably do that with your existing state object if you want, though:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState(current => {
        const {size: {width, height}} = current;
        return {
            ...current,
            shape: width === height ? "square" : "rect"
        };
    });
}, [state.size, state.size.width, state.size.height]);
```

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Example() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        shape: 'square',
        size: {
            width: 100,
            height: 100
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(current => {
            const {size: {width, height}} = current;
            return {
                ...current,
                shape: width === height ? "square" : "rect"
            };
        });
    }, [state.size, state.size.width, state.size.height]);

    function onSizePropInput({target: {name, value}}) {
        setState(current => {
            return {
                ...current,
                size: {
                    ...current.size,
                    [name]: +value
                }
            };
        });
    }

    const {shape, size: {width, height}} = state;
    return <div>
        <div>
            Width: <input type="number" name="width" value={width} onInput={onSizePropInput} />
        </div>
        <div>
            Height: <input type="number" name="height" value={height} onInput={onSizePropInput} />
        </div>
        <div>
            Shape: {shape}
        </div>
    </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note the use of the callback form of `setState` in that. You want the *then-current* version of the state, not the state as it was when the effect callback was first created, since part of what you use for the update isn't a dependency (and so may be stale).